# When callout is made inside a Post-Install script, it fails with uncommitted work pending

Tags: callout, postinstall, calloutexception

When callout is made inside a Post-Install script, it fails with the error

```
You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

If we run the method `Limits.getDMLStatements()`, it returns `0`, which means there is no DML operation to commit or rollback

```
Limits.getDMLStatements(): 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package install is considered as DML operation and [prohibits synchronous callouts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.apex_post_install_script.htm&type=5)

Per documentation,

> It can only perform callouts using an async operation. The callout
> occurs after the script is run and the install is complete and
> committed.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, seems to me a valid answer to issue which someone might have in future.

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious for people who downvote... anyway I spent significant amount of time to figure out this, so decided to be worth post this to make sure I won't spend so much time to investigate this again in the future...